# How can I create a new table from an existing one, saving the new table with the current user's name as part of the table name?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

The following is the code I'm using. I can save the new table with the name I give it in the command line, but how can I include the current user name as part of the table name? Can someone please help?

```
Dim Unm As String = Membership.GetUser(RegisterUser.UserName).UserName.ToString()

    Dim tNm As String = (Unm & "JE").ToString()
   'Connect to DB, open connection, insert data, then close connection.
    njtbConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\MyWeb\App_Data\TTdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
    njtbConn.Open()
    njtbComm = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM UJE AS UserTable1", njtbConn)
    njtbComm.ExecuteNonQuery()

    njtbConn.Close()

    njtbConn.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a select into {table name }from (select * from source) statement.

Then to get the user name you could use :
DECLARE @sys_usr char(30)

SET @sys_usr = SYSTEM_USER

Here is the reference for the select into: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx

You will have to make this a dynamic sql using sp_executesql since you are concatenating the user name into the name of the table.

Comment: EXECUTE sp_executesql 'select * into tbl_'+ @sys_usr +' from sourcetable'

Comment: Thanks alot hivies7519, you've saved my life, i've been dealing with this issue since very early today, i have tryed all possible ways i found online, but none gave me the results i was looking for, again thanks alot.